# How to get my shares amount in ib_insync?

Tags: python, broker, interactive-brokers

I have an Interactive Broker account and use ib_insync python package to work with IB API.

I've bought some shares of one company via multiple transactions. How to get the total amount of shares of that company which I have? I need it to know how much I can sell.

Thanks!

Comment: You should read the API documentation.  http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/positions.html   I don't use insync but there's a user group at https://groups.io/g/insync/messages

Answer (score 2):

Basically you would just need to use the `positions()` function

```
from ib_insync import *
util.startLoop()

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)
ib.positions()
```

From: https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/master/notebooks/ordering.ipynb

[ib_insync documentation](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/_modules/ib_insync/ib.html#IB.positions)